# Scheduling priority considerations

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, cpu

Schedulers in contemporary operating systems implicitly give higher priority to I/O bound process over CPU bound processes. Do you think that while scheduling the processes, CPU bound processes should be given higher priority as compared to I/O bound processes so that the throughput could be increased.

Comment: @FaisalSaleem         I believe it is more about setting priority than giving high priority....

Answer (score 2):

If serving IO is given lower priority it is likely that some input is missed while the processor is executing non-IO processes which is almost certainly bad. That's why higher priority for IO processes is a necessary evil. If this is a problem you need an operating system that schedules otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the consideration is to serve more processes, rather than to complete only one process. Also I agree with @sharptooth that by allowing more I/O request served will allow better handling of I/O. At the same time CPU can serve other process too. It will produce more throughput by the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

An I/O bound task only needs a small amount of CPU time to wake up and collect results and submit the next request.  **But I/O queue sizes are finite, and maybe very small if it doesn't use async I/O** (e.g. open one file and read it, then close it and open another file and read it.)

**So it needs to wake up when the I/O is done to avoid losing huge amounts of I/O throughput.**  When reading a large file, software readahead by the OS can bring data into the pagecache so future `read` system calls can complete fast, and `write` can be buffered, but multiple small files might be scattered around on disk.

Reading from a network might also have a small queue size (socket buffer))0, and for UDP that might mean losing packets.  For TCP, draining the socket buffer makes room for more data that the kernel can send ACKs for.  Unix pipe buffers are often not huge, like perhaps 64 KiB, so failing to wake up a simple reader can lead to the writer blocking, or vice versa if it's the reader that's CPU intensive.

Some I/O bound tasks are actually *interactive*, when the I/O in on keyboard/mouse events, or in response to them, so throughput isn't the only consideration.

A scheduler that achieves slightly higher CPU throughput but can't overlap CPU-bound and I/O bound workloads is not a good scheduler for a general-purpose computer.  e.g. copying or download or uploading a huge file shouldn't slow down much if you're also running a number-crunching simulation that does no I/O.